# Worklight - Updatable static content

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I have this requirement : My WL application have a set of static pages that might be updated any time. Originally the source of all static content is a desktop page that will be transformed by xsl to a mobile friendly content. The problem that I don't want to do that on each request (HA requirement).

I want to get some inspiration on how to architect that without using direct update mechanism (don't want the end user to get notified of these updates).

I should note that pages will change rarely every few month maybe.

I'm thinking about 2 ways of doing that :

1- Making the transformation on adapter side and rely on WL caching so that transformation is not made each time (does that exist ?). But how the adapter will get notified of page change and flush the cache ? Should I program some advanced java based adapter ? (Storing in the cache and having a kind of a job that scans every day for content changes ?)

2- Doing it mobile side but I don't know how to get notified of changes !

Answer (score 1):

Is your only problem with Worklight's Direct Update that the user is being notified and is required to explicitly approve the transfer?

In this case why not use the option of Silent Direct Update?

The property you're looking for is `updateSliently` set to `true` in initOptions.js.
For this to work it is required, obviously, that `connectOnStartup` will be set to `true` as well.

---

perhaps what is doable is to use an adapter to fetch the HTML (or whatever it is) and save it to the device's local storage and then have the app display this content, this way you do not alter the app's web resources and not trigger Direct Update.

Comment: My client likes the direct update (not silent) feature but he don't want to use it to update static content. We will certainly use that feature for other purpose.

Comment: Is your client aware of Silent Direct Update?

Comment: Yes. And we plan to used it because the applications will be developed by phases

Comment: I mean, are they aware of it as a solution for your problem above? The only other way would be to perhaps use AJAX to fetch data, but this also means to disable Direct Update all together for the app because the app will notice the change in web resources checksum, and this will again trigger Direct Update, and since you say you plan on using Direct Update for some aspects of the app, those won't be possible if you will be forced to disable Direct Update...

Comment: Not yet. He wants the static files to be updated silently and keep the noisy direct update feature as programmed.
Tell me what do you think about the server side caching solution ?

Comment: I do not have an educated opinion on it. I don't think this will be feasible if you plan on having Direct Update yet not use it for all, because as I mentioned - changing web resources changes the checksum. Changing the checksum triggers Direct Update. You might be getting into loops, or fetching old web resources, or who knows. It's not a standard flow. Also, you can't have both silent direct update and regular direct update. It's either option 1 or option 2.

Comment: But also, perhaps what is doable is to use an adapter to fetch the HTML (or whatever it is) and save it to the device's local storage and then have the app display this content, this way you do not alter the app's web resources and not trigger Direct Update.

Comment: Ok. I guess charging pages using ajax and storing them into localstorage will be my best option here